# Is every subset of a metric space a metric subspace?

Tags: real-analysis

Is every subset of a metric space a metric subspace? A simple proof does justify that all are subspaces, still, wanted to know if I missed something.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To be completely precise, all subsets of a metric space *equipped with the induced metric* are metric subspaces. You could also equip the subsets with other metrics, and then they wouldn't be metric subspaces.

(Strictly speaking you could also not equip them with a metric at all, and then they aren't metric subspaces because they aren't even metric spaces).

Comment: Yes,  exactly what I meant! Thanks a lot! I'm trying to find if there's any criteria to find if a normal space has a (not- closed) subspace which is not normal, now I can rule out metric spaces.

Answer (score 4):

All the definition of a metric subspace of $(X,d)$ is is a subset $Y\subset X$ together with the metric $d|_{Y\times Y}$. So the subsets themselves aren't metric subspaces, but they can be made into subspaces by giving them a restriction of $d$ as a metric.

Comment: Technically it's $d|_{Y\times Y}$ rather than $d|_Y$.

Comment: Yeah sorry, that's what I meant!

Comment: @user123123 you answer, is for me the useful one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x,p)$ be metric space and letting $Y$ be a non empty subset of $X$. Define the function $§$ on $Y$. $Y$ by $§(x,y)=p(x,y)$ for all $x,y$ in $Y$.Then $(Y,§)$ is also a metric space called a subspace of the metric space $(x,p)$.